# Why I am Unable to prevent redirection when clicking the same button Programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing functionality where I can get addresses when I enter only post code. Normally, when I click next button,I am getting list of addresses. Actually I also want to implement enter button functionality where user will type zipcode in the text-field and press enter and he will be shown list of addresses.

Here is my code:

```
 $('#nxt-button').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 // ajax call for getting all addresses related to entered post code
return false;
});
```

// Enter button functionality

```
  $("#post-code-textfield").keyup(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#nxt-button").click();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
      });
```

Now the problem is that when I press next button directly, preventdefault works but when I press enter key, the page is redirected on next page.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you share HTML?

Comment: Change the keyup event to keydown event, as the event is already taking place when keyup is fired.

Comment: I guess your input field is inside a form and pressing enter is submitting the form. You need to prevent the form from getting submitted. Post your markup to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `keypress` event

```
  $("#post-code-textfield").keypress(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            $("#nxt-button").click();
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
      });
```

Comment: It would be much better to [prevent the form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40971450/542251) then you could resolve both your issues in one go

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the field is inside a form and when you press enter your form it's submitting.All you need is to prevent submit `form`:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
});
```

To prevent form submission `return false` should work too.

Comment: some explanation would be helpful? This is the issue though. Enter submits the form, it doesn't press the button

Answer (score 0):

If Your button has `href` attr, remove it, and perform redirect directly in `click` listener.